# How to auto backup an always running foreground app

Tags: android, backup

How can this be handled?

I can use

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupInForeground="true" />
```

but then my foregorund service is stopped. Is there any automatic backup process that works with always running apps and does not shut them down while backing up data?

Alternatively, starting the backup manually from within my app would be an option for me as well (start backup, stop service, do backup, restart service). The advantage of this would be that data restoration after reinstall is done automatically at least... I don't really need the constant auto backup, manually triggered backups would be fine as well (I know I can do this via adb, but I've not found anything to allow to user to do this from within the app)

Comment: Any solution for this? Do you know if atleast the system restarts the service once it is killed and backed up?